# Setting up Log4Net to log output from a Class Library

Tags: c#, log4net, .net-assembly

I'm trying to setup Log4Net (this is my first time using Log4Net) to log to a text file in an assembly. I'm not getting any errors, but it's also not working. I can breakpoint the lines where I am logging my output and see that they are reached, but like I say nothing happens.

Where am I going wrong?

I have added the following to my `packages.config` file, inside the `<packages>` attribute:

```xml
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="c:\CTI\log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I have added the following line to `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

I added the Log4Net assembly using NuGet and I am logging like this:

```
private log4net.ILog _Log;
_Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
_Log.Debug("FooBar");
```

Like I say, no errors but nothing happens either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing that is wrong is that you are adding the log4net configuration section to the nuget config file (`packages.config`).

You can have the configuration in the app/web config or in a separate file to which you point from the appSettings, e.g.
configuration is in a file called `config.log4net` (the `copy to output directory` attribute of the file is set to `copy always`) and you add the following entry in app/web.config:

```
<add key="log4net.config" value="config.log4net"/>
```

If you don't want to depend on a web/app configuration, you can set the [ConfigFileExtension](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfiguratorAttribute.ConfigFileExtension.html) property of the `XmlConfiguratorAttribute` attribute in `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFileExtension = "log4net", Watch = true)]
```

Then name the log4net configuration file the same as your exe/assembly plus the configured extension, e.g. `MyApplication.exe.log4net` or `MyLibrary.dll.log4net`

Another thing that is wrong is your appender filter. The range that you have set excludes DEBUG level, which you expect to log. Here are all [logging levels](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html):

```
ALL
DEBUG
INFO
WARN
ERROR
FATAL
OFF
```

As you can see, `DEBUG` is not between `INFO` and `FATAL`.